# Spot the typo in this code snippet causing page to not load, php, html - probably a missing or misplaced character?

Tags: php, html

I've been editing the following block of code and now when I use it then the page will not load but I also don't get anything in the error log either. I am guessing this has happened due to a missing or misplaced character somewhere but have looked and looked over it and cannot spot what it is! does it stand out to anyone?

```
<?php if ($logourldecoded != "") { ?>

<?php if ($companyname != "") { ?>
<img src="images/site-logo-high-res.png"  alt="logo" style="max-height:91px; max-width:372px; min-height:91px;" />
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="companynameclass" style="font-size: <?php echo $data[font_size]; ?>;">
<?php echo $companyname; ?>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $logourldecoded; ?>"  alt="logo" style="max-height:91px; max-width:372px; min-height:91px;" />
<?php } ?>
```

I also know it's not that any of the data I'm calling with $NAME_HERE being incorrect or missing as if i just echo them all indiviually they are exactly as expected and before my edits where showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `}` to close the inner IF

```
<?php 
if ($logourldecoded != "") { 
?>
<?php 
    if ($companyname != "") { 
?>
        <img src="images/site-logo-high-res.png"  alt="logo" style="max-height:91px; max-width:372px; min-height:91px;" />
<?php 
        } else { 
?>
        <div class="companynameclass" style="font-size: <?php echo $data[font_size]; ?>;">
            <?php echo $companyname; ?>
        </div>
<?php   
        // the missing line
        }
?>
<?php 
} else { 
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $logourldecoded; ?>"  alt="logo" style="max-height:91px; max-width:372px; min-height:91px;" />
<?php 
} 
?>
```

You might consider not placing `<?php ..?>` tags on each line, it makes the code almost completely unreadable, and whats unreadable is by definition unmaintainable

Comment: Perfect thank you, sometimes I think you can just look too hard for things and thus end up not spotting them at all! Thanks for the tip on the <?php ..?> tags, I had just laid it out like that as I found it easier while working on it to understand the flow of the if-else things going on and now that the code is executing I can see that didn't help me understand the flow any better as i still mixed up the order slightly but have corrected it and got it now working exactly as I wanted. thanks again!